# Informatica Cloud Error: Connection error to snowflake null response for request post

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Submitting an interesting Q&A thread that may be of value to other Snowflake Users on Stack Overflow)

---

In my project , we are loading to Snowflake via Informatica cloud from Azure blob.

The test connection at Informatica end is successful and I could get the tables but data is not loading to the table.

```
MAPPING> JAVA PLUGIN_1762 [2019-08-29 16:11:39.087] [DEBUG] ttp.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)

at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SFTrustManager.fetchOcspResponse(SFTrustManager.java:838)
```

... 43 more

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)   
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
```

... 54 more

```
MAPPING> JAVA PLUGIN_1762 [2019-08-29 16:11:39.087] [DEBUG] 1273154 [main] WARN net.snowflake.client.jdbc.RestRequest - Null response for request=POST https://totalgp.west-europe.azure.snowflakecomputing.com/session/v1/login-request?warehouse=DEV_WH&roleName=UK_DEV_RW&requestId=05b37454-a92b-40e9-ad06-03a7c540784f&retryCount=1&request_guid=cb1acefe-69a7-4c67-9579-0f2bcb34011f HTTP/1.1
MAPPING> JAVA PLUGIN_1762 [2019-08-29 16:11:39.088] [DEBUG] 1273154 [main] WARN net.snowflake.client.jdbc.RestRequest - Null response for request=POST https://totalgp.west-europe.azure.snowflakecomputing.com/session/v1/login-request?warehouse=DEV_WH&roleName=UK_DEV_RW&requestId=05b37454-a92b-40e9-ad06-03a7c540784f&retryCount=1&request_guid=cb1acefe-69a7-4c67-9579-0f2bcb34011f HTTP/1.1
MAPPING> JAVA PLUGIN_1762 [2019-08-29 16:11:39.088] [DEBUG] 1273155 [main] ERROR net.snowflake.client.jdbc.RestRequest - Stop retrying since elapsed time due to network issues has reached timeout. Elapsed=2546202 milliseconds, timeout=60 seconds
MAPPING> JAVA PLUGIN_1762 [2019-08-29 16:11:39.088] [DEBUG] 1273155 [main] ERROR net.snowflake.client.jdbc.RestRequest - Stop retrying since elapsed time due to network issues has reached timeout. Elapsed=2546202 milliseconds, timeout=60 seconds
MAPPING> CMN_1761 [2019-08-29 16:11:39.101] Timestamp Event: [Thu Aug 29 16:11:39 2019]
MAPPING> JAVA PLUGIN_1762 [2019-08-29 16:11:39.101] [ERROR] com.informatica.powercenter.sdk.SDKException: com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.runtime.exception.InitializationException
at com.informatica.cloud.adapter.cci.runtime.CCIGroupOperation.init(CCIGroupOperation.java:120)
at com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.writer.runtime.GenericWriterTargetDriver.initGroupOperation(Unknown Source)
at com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.writer.runtime.GenericWriterTargetDriver.init(Unknown Source)
MAPPING> CMN_1761 [2019-08-29 16:11:39.101] Timestamp Event: [Thu Aug 29 16:11:39 2019]
MAPPING> JAVA PLUGIN_1762 [2019-08-29 16:11:39.101] [ERROR] 
MAPPING> CMN_1761 [2019-08-29 16:11:39.101] Timestamp Event: [Thu Aug 29 16:11:39 2019]
MAPPING> JAVA PLUGIN_1762 [2019-08-29 16:11:39.101] [ERROR] at com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.writer.runtime.GenericWriterTargetDriver.init(Unknown Source)
MAPPING> CMN_1761 [2019-08-29 16:11:39.101] Timestamp Event: [Thu Aug 29 16:11:39 2019]
MAPPING> SDKS_38500 [2019-08-29 16:11:39.102] Plug-in #449900's target [TESTAZSF] failed in method [init].
MAPPING> CMN_1761 [2019-08-29 16:11:39.102] Timestamp Event: [Thu Aug 29 16:11:39 2019]
MAPPING> TM_6006 [2019-08-29 16:11:39.102] Error initializing DTM for session [s_mtt_01038F0Z000000000005].
MAPPING> CCI_GroupOperation_1000 [2019-08-29 16:11:39.104] [INFO] After the run-time engine writes records, it runs the following post-SQL query: []
```

***Q:***
Can some one please guide here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***A:***
It looks like the request response is NULL. Can you check with your internal networking team if there is a proxy server configured or something that might otherwise be blocking the communication?

---

***Q:***
The Proxy authorization is been bypassed , but the error remains the same.

After it reach the SDK plug-in

MAPPING> SDKS_38029 [2019-09-04 11:06:39.981] Loaded plug-in 449900: [plugin description].

MAPPING> SDKS_38024 [2019-09-04 11:06:39.998] Plug-in 449900 initialization complete.

MAPPING> SDKS_38017 [2019-09-04 11:06:39.998] Writer SDK plug-in intialization complete.

the job remains there for 10min without any further action.

The job get terminated with the following error.

[ERROR] com.informatica.powercenter.sdk.SDKException: com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.runtime.exception.InitializationException at com.informatica.cloud.adapter.cci.runtime.CCIGroupOperation.init(CCIGroupOperation.java:120) at com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.writer.runtime.GenericWriterTargetDriver.initGroupOperation(Unknown Source) at com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.writer.runtime.GenericWriterTargetDriver.init(Unknown Source)

***A:***
It still sounds like a networking, proxy, or firewall issue due to the timeout (in my opinion). Your internal networking team should be able to trace the traffic to assist on where the communication is getting blocked. Perhaps some URLs need to be whitelisted? I also noticed similar errors on the Informatica forums. Might help to look through some of their potential solutions (links below)?

https://network.informatica.com/thread/59666

https://kb.informatica.com/solution/23/pages/58/499407.aspx

https://network.informatica.com/thread/78386

---

***ANY OTHER IDEAS, RECOMMENDATIONS, ETC.??***